# How the network packets are transferred to the memory on linux?

Tags: linux, memory, cpu

Is there some command or tool for monitoring network packets and how those packets are handled by the memory and than proceeded to the CPU on linux platform?

Using tcpdump I can capture many apache requests for example but I don't know how those packages are assigned to some process id.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When an server process starts it issues some system calls (`socket()` and `listen()`). The system then opens the port and creates a socket file descriptor for the process to interact with. You can see this with:

Find the Apache master process id:

```
root@frisbee:~# ps -ef | grep apache | grep root
root     27440     1  0 16:06 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start
```

Go to `/proc/$pid/fd` and view the sockets:

```
root@frisbee:~# ls -l /proc/27440/fd | grep socket
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 apr 16 16:12 3 -> socket:[518486]
lrwx------ 1 root root 64 apr 16 16:12 4 -> socket:[518487]
```

Here you can see there are two sockets opened by Apache. The Apache process internally can use file descriptors 3 & 4 to read/write data through the network connection.

You can find the mapping between sockets and listening ports with `lsof`:

```
root@frisbee:~# lsof | egrep 'IPv6.*(518486|518487)'
apache2   27440                  root    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   27445              www-data    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   27446              www-data    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   27447              www-data    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   27448              www-data    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
apache2   27449              www-data    4u     IPv6             518487       0t0        TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

There are multiple Apache processes using the same file descriptor (opened by the process running as `root`, because it is a privileged port). These are the Apache workers.

An easier way to view the link between port and process is to use the `netstat` command:

```
mtak@frisbee:~$ sudo netstat -tulpn | grep apache
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      4269/apache2
```